# Count DISTINCT rows from multiple joined tables in MySQL with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: Businesses, Inspections, and Violations. I have the following query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.address, b.city, b.state, b.type, i.date
FROM businesses AS b
RIGHT JOIN inspections i ON i.business_id = b.id
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT inspection_id FROM violations) AS v ON v.inspection_id = i.id
WHERE b.type = 'hospital' AND i.date BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-01-03";
```

I want to find out how many distinct violations (easy, this is the number of rows), inspections, and businesses that were returned in the result. I tried using `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` but I wasn't able to get it to work.

What I need is something like:

```
table      | count
------------------
businesses | 10
inspections| 23
violations | 100
```

Comment: As an aside, note that no one ever actually uses RIGHT JOIN

Comment: What should I use instead of RIGHT JOIN?

Comment: Most use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Show the query where you tried to use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` so we can see what you did wrong and tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I use LEFT JOIN's all the time. Not sure how I would get the result that I need using a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: You probably need something like `COUNT(DISTINCT v.inspection_id)`

Comment: If `businesses` is the parent table, you should be using `LEFT JOIN` here.

Comment: @Strawberry It's not true that "no one uses RIGHT JOIN." That's fake news! RIGHT JOIN can be useful to increase readability of some queries. Joins have a left-to-right order of operation. So if you need to do an outer join to the result of a pair of inner-joined tables, you could use parentheses around the joined tables, or you could use RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: Come on @BillKarwin, it's vanishingly rare - just look how many results pop up when you search for one vs the other in this very site.

Comment: It's rare, because most cases of outer join don't fall into the scenario I described. But it's misleading to say no one EVER uses a right join. That's an unequivocal statement that's intended to convince the reader that it has no use at all, which is not true.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Strawberry on this one. While there are are legitimate cases where RIGHT JOIN improves readability, they are so vanishingly rare that the umbrella statement is generally "true" and most appropriate uses should probably be accompanied by the usual code comments acknowledging this fact you tend to see in such situations. _In most cases, RIGHT JOINs are just LEFT JOINs someone decided should be read backwards._

Comment: It's much easier to understand `main table left join optional data`, instead if `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: BTW, those conditions in the `WHERE` clause make the right outer joins return inner join results anyway... (Move to `ON` clause to get true outer join result.)

Comment: The issue is the main table is violations. I want one row for each violation that that has information about the inspection under which it was observed and the business where it was observed. Doesn't my query do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, it will put all the counts in a single row:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS businesses, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) AS inspections,
       COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) AS violations
FROM businesses AS b
INNER JOIN inspections AS i ON b.id = i.business_id AND i.date BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-01-03"
LEFT JOIN violations AS v ON i.id = v.inspection_id
WHERE b.type = 'hospital'
```

Using `INNER JOIN` will only return the count of businesses that have been inspected during that date range. If you want the count of all businesses, use `OUTER JOIN`.